# Jersey JSON marshalling of nested generic produces null

Tags: java, json, generics, jersey, jax-rs

Having an issue trying to marshall into JSON a HashMap nested in a List using Jersey 1.11.

Here's a snippet of a Jersey endpoint which produces MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON via the returned Response object:

**DataDTO.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataDTO {
  ...
  private List<GenericEntity<HashMap<String, String>> dataHierarchy;

  public List<GenericEntity<HashMap<String, String>> getDataHierarchy() { return dataHierarchy; }
  public void setDataHierarchy(List<GenericEntity<HashMap<String, String>> dh) { dataHierarchy = dh; }
}
```

**Jersey resource class:**

```
@Get
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/summary")
public Response getSummary() {
  ....
  DataDTO dto = new DataDTO();
  List<GenericEntity<HashMap<String,String>>> genericEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (HashMap<String, String> hashMapEntity : summary.getDataHierarchy()) {
      GenericEntity<HashMap<String, String>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<HashMap<String, String>>(hashMapEntity) {};
      genericEntityList.add(genericEntity);
  }
  dto.setDataHierarchy(genericEntityList);
  return Response.ok(dto).build();
}
```

The DTO is part of the 'natural class set' and its JAXBContext resolver context is configured to use natural notation and root unwrapping as so:

```
new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().rootUnwrapping(true).build(),
                    naturalClassSet.toArray(new Class[naturalClassSet.size()]));
```

When, for example there are 5 entries in the list, the response JSON ends up looking like so:

```
{"dataHierarychy":[null, null, null, null, null]}
```

I've also tried changing the dataHierarchy property of DataDTO so that each generic data structure is wrapped in a GenericEntity:

```
private GenericEntity<List<GenericEntity<HashMap<String,String>>>>
```

This results in simply:

```
{"dataHierarychy":null}
```

Comment: Solution: I ended working around this by creating DTOs to replace these ADTs.